# How to use an existing button function in a different winform of the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Is there any way, within a `WinForms` solution, to have one Button's function be referenced in a different Form under a different Button?

An example of this would be:

`Form1.cs`:

```
public static int math = -1;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "How to make this work";
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Confused.jpg");
    math++;
}
```

`Form2.cs`:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Referencing the `Form1.button1_Click` does not seem to work, giving me an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Form1.button1_Click(object, EventArgs)'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Form1 is a type, not an object.  Winforms is relentlessly OOPy, you'll suffer for a while when the distinction between types and objects is still vague.  Get ahead by googling "c# how to add an event".

Comment: If `Form1` is still *alive* when `Form2` is active, you could have a `public` method in `Form1` and move the code that's now in `button1_Click` there. You can then call this method both from `Form1` and `Form2`.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Events seem like the correct solution for what I'm doing! Thanks!